# Android - Saving custom object - Shared Preferences or Database?

Tags: android, database, listview, object, save

I'm creating a location based reminder application.

I've got a custom object called Reminder, which stores latitude, longitude, the location name and the subject of the reminder - Aswell as what profile it belongs to.

I'm then inputting the location name and sujbect into a ListView (Using cardlibs here too).

However now I need to save the data for when I close the application, and was wondering the best way to go about this - Do I store the entire 'Reminder' object or do I just store multiple pieces of data in Shared Preferences / A database.

This is my code - It's very inefficient/Ugly:

**Reminder:**

```
public class Reminder implements Parcelable {

public double latitude;
public double longitude;
public String subject;
public String locationName;

public String profile;

public Reminder() {

}

public Reminder(Parcel in) {
    String[] data = new String[5];

    in.readStringArray(data);
    this.subject = data[0];
    this.locationName = data[1];
    this.latitude = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);
    this.longitude = Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
    this.profile = data[4];

}

public String getProfile() {
    return profile;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public String getLocationName() {
    return locationName;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setProfile(String profile) {
    this.profile = profile;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public void setLocationName(String locationName) {
    this.locationName = locationName;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeStringArray(new String[] { this.subject, this.locationName,
            String.valueOf(this.latitude), String.valueOf(this.longitude), this.profile });
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Reminder> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Reminder>() {

    public Reminder createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Reminder(source); // using parcelable constructor
    }

    public Reminder[] newArray(int size) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Reminder[size];
    }

};
```

}

**List using a fragment:**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public static ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

Reminder reminder;

public HomeFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    reminder = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableExtra("reminder");

    Card card = new Card(getActivity());

    CardHeader cardHeader = new CardHeader(getActivity());

    if (reminder != null) {
        cardHeader.setTitle(reminder.getSubject());
        card.addCardHeader(cardHeader);
        card.setTitle(reminder.getLocationName());
        cards.add(card);
    }

    CardArrayAdapter mCardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(
            getActivity(), cards);

    CardListView listView = (CardListView) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.card_list);
    mCardArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    if (listView != null)
        listView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);




}
```

Any criticism on how my code could of been wrote better would also be really beneficial, as I feel I'm being a huge rookie and missing something obvious which would make it more efficient.

Thanks!

Comment: this belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, never heard of it until now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the choice to use shared preferences vs a database hinges on a number of things:

1)  How many objects are we talking about?  How complex are they?

2)  Do you intend on searching/manipulating these objects or are you just saving/loading them.

3)  Do you intend to export/move/send objects?

4)  Do you want the objects to be recoverable across application contexts - that is beyond only the single app in question.

In your specific case I would use a database.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

As you can see in the docs here prefs isn't really intended for Object storage - it's for key value pairs.  While you could store an object as a number of key value pairs in the shared prefs and reconstruct from there, you would have to go through some weird model conversions to do this for multiple objects.  In short it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: If I were to use a database, would there be much use in creating the custom object 'Reminder'? Rather when a 'Reminder' object is created, it is instead inputted into the database with the respective data. The ListView would then be repopulated everytime the fragment is created using the data from the database.

Comment: That depends on a few things - mostly what you intened on doing with the reminders.  Check out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html  for a nice way to translate direct from your DB to a List View

Comment: The reminders are simply there as proximity alerts. The reminders would just be in a list with a function to edit or delete them. As to why the metadata has to be contained within the ListView so the user can view and edit it. Thanks for these links, I'll be taking a closer look.